# Classifier weighted towards recall?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka

I have a classification problem where getting true positives is much more important than true negatives.

To be clear, I know that roughly 10% of my population are actual positives, but I can assign some proportion (say 30%) of the population to be classified as positives without much cost, above all else I need to make sure that the actual positives are covered by this set.

Unfortunately the classification tools I am using in WEKA seem to be balancing precision and recall, so that it is a) not assigning as many positives as it is allowed to, and b) getting quite a bad recall value.

Is there a standard way of approaching this problem?  My first guess would be to weight the cost function towards recall rather than F-score, but I don't see an easy way to do this in WEKA.

Answer (score 2):

Optimizing recall in model selection will likely yield trivial classifiers that label everything as positive (perfect recall), so that won't help.

I suggest plotting [ROC curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) or Precision-Recall curves for your existing models to determine a decision threshold with the recall you desire. After that you can compare which models have the best specificity or precision (direct result of ROC and PR curves, respectively).

Comment: Yeah I thought about something like this.  Unfortunately I think I need to do some optimisation before the ROC stage - at the moment there are a lot of positives getting a very low score.

Comment: I agree that weighting 100% recall is a bad idea, but there are compromises, like the F_{beta} score - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score

Comment: Try weighting positives (or take multiple samples of them) to force a classifier to put more emphasis on positives.

Comment: @sweezyjeezy However, the F1 score does not give higher weights towards Recall. It just assures that preference is given to procedures that prevent 0% recall and 100% precision to have a mean of 50%, compared to 50%-50%, which is often much preferred.

Comment: Taking multiple samples is a good idea, I will try this

Comment: @PascalvKooten - I meant the F_β score which generalises F_1.  From wikipedia : 'F_β measures the effectiveness of retrieval with respect to a user who attaches β times as much importance to recall as precision

Comment: AFAIK, each learning algorithm tries to optimize some measure (generally error or accuracy), and it is not easy to modify that. Alternatively, in WEKA you can use the `CostSensitiveClassifier` with an appropriate cost matrix to promote the errors or hits you need. The suitable costs are not easy to determine, unless they are known at the real world - so you have to test with some of them. A nice idea is to start testing costs exactly with the inverse of your distribution.